# Giant Power Pro chainring compatibility

Tags: road-bike, chainring, giant

I have Giant Power Pro on Ultegra R8000 crankset. Does anyone know if the Giant Power Pro is compatible with other chainrings?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace the chainring?  If so any R8000-compatible 110mm BCD chainring should work (I think Absolute Black, among others, makes them).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the [power meter in question](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/global/showcase/powerpro) is simply mounted to a stock R8000 crankset. hence, any rings made for that generation of Shimano cranks should fit. Rings made for the previous generation will not. Many power meters have trouble calculating accurate power if you use oval chainrings, and I don’t know if the Power Pro is one such meter.

Comment: The power pro based on shimano 11 speed has trouble calculating accurate power whatever chainring you use ;-)